# Easiest way to connect to SQL Server on Flask app for search query?

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking to give my Flask app data to query, since the end app will be like a search engine + calculator.

I'm not sure what the easiest way to connect SQL Server data to the Flask app is, and how to query based on certain fields.

I've looked into Elasticsearch and it's a little too advanced for me at the moment, and wasn't sure if there was an easier way.

I've also used PYODBC in the past to build Pandas dataframes based on query results, but I was selecting * from the given table. For this, I want to use the user input and then query the database based on that input and return the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you should have a look at SQLAlchemy. Some info on how to use it with MS SQL Server may be found [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html).